# What happened to Theon's crew?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones, Winterfell is taken over by Theon Greyjoy and his skeleton crew, the city is later besieged by House Bolton, Theon is knocked out by his crew and handed over to the bastard Ramsay. This much I know. But what happens to Theon's crew after this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [GoT Wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ramsay_Snow) they were flayed alive by Ramsay's men.

> However, the castle is sacked by Ramsay afterwards and instead of
>   letting the ironborn walk free, he flays them alive.

To say the truth I don't remember that being explained in the TV show.
Perhaps this is based on the events from the books, where he also killed the crew, but the [events there](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Theon_Greyjoy#In_the_books) where different.

Edit: Turns out that there is a [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5g5UvrhJFVQ&t=102) where Roose Bolton and Walder Frey are discussing the ironborn fate. Thanks Will Feldman!

Comment: I don't recall this being [shown explicitly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eisjVKo1Wkc), but considering that is the modus operandi of the Boltons, this is the expected run of events.

Comment: I think I remember a scene with Roose Bolton telling Walder Fray about it later.  He says he had told Ramsay to make a deal with Iron Islanders, but "Ramsay does things his own way".

Comment: @Will Feldman You're absolutely right, I've edited my answer.